# Avoiding data labels from crossing one another Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, database, function, matplotlib, text

I am plotting a dataset and within the dataset , it gives datalabels to 5 points that are equidistant from each other. I am trying have the data labels to not go over the borders of the graph and also have them not touching one another. Is there a function I could use that will ensure no two points will be touching one another or go over the borders of the graph.

Code:

```
#figsize of the charts
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[9, 7], constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(6, 3)

#Plotting the compounding amount 
a1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:3, 0]) #subplot (row, column)
a1.set_title('Compounding Amount')
a1.set_ylabel('PnL of the asset')
a1.set_xlabel('Number of trades')
#prints out the colours blue while acending and red while decending 
colors_CA= ['b' if a < b else 'r' for a,b in zip(Amount_list,Amount_list[1:])]
for i in range(len(b_post)):
    try:
        a1.plot(b_post[i:i+2], Amount_list[i:i+2], color=colors_CA[i])
        for i in range(0, len(b_post), len(b_post)//5):
            
            label = f"({b_post[i]},{round(Amount_list[i],1)})"
            a1.annotate(label, # this is the text
                         (b_post[i],Amount_list[i]), # this is the point to label
                         textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
                         xytext=(0,10), # distance from text to points (x,y)
                         ha='center') # horizontal alignment can be left, right or center
    except:
        break
```

Graph:

[image]

Comment: You can use `adjustText` library in python. See this: https://adjusttext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html